# If/else statement won't execute in a function

Tags: python, json

I'm making a function where I can see if an entered code already has an active account associated with it

for this I simply made this function:

```py
    def check_code():
        r = requests.get(url)
        response = r.json()

        if response['account']['active'] is True:
            status = "active account "

        else:
            status = "not active account "
        return status
```

now when the key `account` isn't present I want the `else` statement to run

However I get:
`KeyError: 'account'`.

The response code shows this:
`activated: "NOT_ACTIVE"`

My whole if/else statement is to just check if an account is active or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code.

```
def check_code():
    r = requests.get(url)
    response = r.json()

    if (account := response.get('account')) and account.get('active'):
        return "active account "

    else:
        return "not active account "
```

Comment: You can only do this in Python 3.8.

Comment: This works! However, what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: @genovese You're trying to access a key that doesn't exist, which is why the exception is being thrown. `.get()` gives `None` back if the requested key does not exist (or a default value if you give it as the second argument)

Comment: Thanjk you! However, now I get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` everyonce in a while? (appears to be random after `x` amount of checks)

Comment: It's always a best practice to use get method in the dictionary. Bcz get method returns None is it not found any specific key. So your further execution will gone through else part.
And In your approach, response["account"] raise the KeyError if key not found which is "account" here.
So your program exit rather than executing further.